# How does python 3.8 in virtual environment construct sys.path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, sys.path

I noticed something weird when I inspect the `sys.path` in my python3.8 virtual env. Specifically, I have the following hierarchy in my `playground`:

```
.
├── mmdetection
├── monodepth2
├── py37
├── py38
└── qd-track
```

When I invoke the python environment `py38` and look at the `sys.path` members, I noticed the following pattern:

```
dian@ubuntu:~/playground$ ls
mmdetection  monodepth2  py37  py38  qd-track
dian@ubuntu:~/playground$ source py38/bin/activate
(py38) dian@ubuntu:~/playground$ python
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:14:01) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/home/dian/playground/mmdetection', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/terminaltables-3.1.0-py3.8.egg', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmpycocotools-12.0.3-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg', '/home/dian/playground/qd-track', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/motmetrics-1.2.0-py3.8.egg', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmcv-1.1.5-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xmltodict-0.12.0-py3.8.egg', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy-1.5.3-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_benchmark-3.2.3-py3.8.egg']
```

Interestingly, `mmdetection` and `qd-track`, which are on the same level of `py38`, got picked up by `sys.path`, while `monodepth2` and `py37` weren't. I changed the name of `mmdetection` to `mmdetection2`, as well as created a couple of new empty folders `detectron`, `detectron2`, which made the current folder look like:

```
.
├── detectron
├── detectron2
├── mmdetection2
├── monodepth2
├── py37
├── py38
└── qd-track
```

Then I tried to print sys.path again, and got:

```
(py38) dian@ubuntu:~/playground$ python
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:14:01) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/home/dian/playground/detectron2', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/terminaltables-3.1.0-py3.8.egg', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmpycocotools-12.0.3-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg', '/home/dian/playground/qd-track', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/motmetrics-1.2.0-py3.8.egg', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmcv-1.1.5-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xmltodict-0.12.0-py3.8.egg', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy-1.5.3-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg', '/home/dian/playground/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytest_benchmark-3.2.3-py3.8.egg']
```

This time, `mmdetection2` disappeared, `detectron2` got picked up while `detectron` was not. This is so weird, since the paths seem to be detected by python on the fly instead of being read from some fixed indexes. And exactly how they are detected is confusing to me. I inspected `PYTHONPATH` and it's empty.

What's more interesting, I tried switching to the `py37` environment, which sits side-by-side to `py38`, and nothing described above happened:

```
(py38) dian@ubuntu:~/playground$ deactivate
dian@ubuntu:~/playground$ source py37/bin/activate
(py37) dian@ubuntu:~/playground$ python
Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:50:52) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/dian/playground/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/dian/playground/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/terminaltables-3.1.0-py3.7.egg']
```

So, I guess this might due to some new changes to the loading mechanics starting from python3.8? And, what exactly behavior should I expect when I make use of sys.path? The official documentation doesn't give an exact list of items to be included in sys.path.

By the way I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS; `py37` and `py38` are created via virtualenv.

Comment: As an aside, please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions